# ASP.NET MVC - storing data in ram

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some data in .txt file that i would like to load into RAM memory during Application_Start(), so that i can use this data globally over my asp.net mvc application. How can i do that?

Comment: I didn't try anything, i don't really know how can i do that.

Comment: Memory, Ram same thing, Session?

Comment: What kind of data do you want to load into RAM/Memory? Do you need it for all web requests?

Comment: I need to load a short list of strings into memory, and yes, i need it for all web requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats is better than session I think, do you can use on all Application.

```
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Application["PerfilLevel"] = "0";


        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

On DAL

```
int teste = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Application["PerfilLevel"]);
```

On Controller

```
int teste = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Application["PerfilLevel"]);
```

Note: Same value...

Answer (score 2):

If the data is by client, then use Session

```
Session["value"] = valueForCurrentUser;
```

If the data is global and the same for every user, then use Cache.

```
Cache.Add("value", valueForEveryUser, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, onRemove);
```

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Store the text in a Session so it can be disposed of after the user closes the Browser `Session["MyText"] = txtfile.ToString();`

Comment: But isn't session limited to a single user or something like that?

Comment: @ojek If you want all users to access a file then it will need to be stored on the server and each instance of the application that is running (per client) will need to get that text file. Why do you need this to be globally accessed by many running instances of the site?

Comment: It will be a list of blacklisted IPs, so basically i need every request to check if its IP is in that list, and i need to check it only once. So it would be very uneffective if i needed to read that from the disk, since that list would be kinda small.